# Selecting Top 10 Employee Salaries

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database for salaries of employees.

Here are the `Salaries` Table fields:

```
emp_no INT(11)
salary INT(11)
from_date DATE
to_date DATE
```

I'm trying to get the top 10 employee salaries, non-duplicate employees. With the code below I can get the maximum salary for the emp_no, but my from_date and to_date are defaulting to the earliest date values for that emp_no.

```
select emp_no, max(salary) as salary, from_date, to_date
from salaries
group by emp_no
order by salary DESC
limit 10
```

I assumed `GROUP BY` would keep the values of the dates that matched up with the salary and `emp_no`, but after thinking about it a bit it doesn't make sense for it to do so.

Any help with how to get the correct date values would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you need from_date, to_date in SELECT?

Comment: The issue is you **can't** include field on the `select` if you dont include it on the `group by`

Comment: Requirement for the assignment.

Comment: do same `emp_no` appear several time on the table or is the primary key on the table?

Comment: So, you need both the top salaries as well as the dates when those salaries has been being paid, right?

Comment: Correct, @JuanCarlosOropeza SQL does work for me. I was thinking I might have to do a join and match up based on salary and emp_no, but was hoping there may be an easier option.

Answer (score 0):

First table will contain the top 10 salaries.

Then you check original table to see which row matches `emp_no` and `salary` to get dates.

```
SELECT S.*
FROM  
    (SELECT emp_no, max(salary) as salary
     FROM salaries
     GROUP BY emp_no
     ORDER BY salary DESC
     limit 10
   ) maxSal
INNER JOIN salaries S
   ON maxSal.emp_no = S.emp_no
  AND maxSal.salary = S.salary
```

Comment: So the only way for you to do it is with a join, and match up the emp_no and salary?

Comment: In other rdbms like `Oracle` or `SqlServer` you could use `row_number()` but mySQL is very limited

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. Now to add the name from another relation.

Comment: How would this query behave when you have a single employee with two periods with the same max salary?

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko You will get a random row. But in this case I think is safe assume you wont get the same salary.