# Finding biggest increase in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing an exercise where I have to find which employee had the biggest increase in salary during his time in the company. These are the two tables I need to use.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (emp_no));

CREATE TABLE salaries (
emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
salary      INT             NOT NULL,
from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
# FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, from_date));
```

I used "MySQL8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode" to do the query displayed below:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, MAX(salary)-MIN(salary) AS 'Max' 
FROM employees JOIN salaries using(emp_no)
GROUP BY emp_no
ORDER BY Max DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Does this query ensures that I am getting the correct result? Is there a faster way to do this?

EDIT: added GROUP BY

Comment: An [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) will help tremendously

Comment: No GROUP BY needed?!?

Comment: Oh sorry @jarlh GROUP BY emp_no

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What do you mean by a faster way. The only way to get employee info and salary is by joining. And you are only using 1 join so that's fine. And by faster you mean faster than instantly? Because this query is as bare as you can get it IMO.

Comment: Ok thanks @RonNabuurs. Regarding the query itself is it really  providing the result intended?

Comment: Your query seems fine. What it doesn't do is account for ties (two or more employees having the same biggest salary increase). And then there may be an employee who changed jobs inside the company and has a lower paid job now. Then the max salary would be for their former job and the min salary for the current, and the query would calculate wrongly.

Comment: @Robert Kock: The `salaries` table has no `first_name` and `last_name`, so you cannot use it for the join. The tables are related by `emp_no`, so this must be used. Maybe it's `GROUP BY emp_no` that confuses you. But this, too, is fine. `emp_no` uniquely identifies an employee including their `first_name` and `last_name`. Some DBMS don't allow us to `GROUP BY emp_no` and then access the unaggregated `first_name` and `last_name`, but this makes those DBMS less standard-compliant.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Sorry, I meant `group by` instead of `join`. Deleted my previous comment.

Comment: there is an error in your select statement max() is looking through and picking out the highest value in the column And min() looks for the smallest value  what you need is a column for start_salary and a column for current_salary and then  `current_salary - start_salary`

Comment: @user9609362 check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854499/selecting-top-10-employee-salaries?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

"Biggest increase in salary" is ambiguous. You have found the biggest difference between the highest and lowest salaries. That is a very reasonable interpretation of the question, but there are others.

For instance, someone might have started at a high salary and then been demoted, so their highest salary is the first. This suggests another reasonable interpretation: the absolute value of the difference between the most recent salary and the first salary. That is a bit trickier to calculate in MySQL.

Another interpretation is the biggest *percentage* increase. So, an increase from $50,000 to $60,000 would be considered "bigger" than one from $500,000 to $550,000, because the percentage is bigger. Of course, this could be applied to either biggest/smallest or latest/first.

Similar questions could also have an answer regarding the *increase per year* in the salary.

So, the question is ambiguous, but you have a perfectly reasonable interpretation and your query implements this. I would not call the column `max`, because it is more appropriately called `diff`.